# Use Citrix Receiver (ICA client) on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, citrix

I used to use Citrix receiver on Ubuntu 16.04 for a while Switching to 18.04, I want to continue using Citrix.

I downloaded and installed citrix receiver 13.8 following this official guide without any errors: https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/receiver/linux/current-release/install.html

When I triy to vonnect using a provided connection file (.ica), I receive the following error message in a window:

> Verbindung mit '0.0.0.2 - Desktop EMEA' kann nicht hergestellt werden.
>   Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden.

**English: File or directory not found**

I tried to debug by setting `PrintLogThreshold=6` in the connection file. Unfortunately o additional information about the error is logged.

Using the same connection on the old Ubuntu 16.04 installation works as usual at the same time.

How can I debug? Why is the IP-address all-zero?

Comment: https://discussions.citrix.com/topic/323985-cannot-connect-to-0002-published-app-name-most-distros/  2nd reply: default.ica.  ProxyUseFQDN=On needs to be "Off"

Comment: also check https://discussions.citrix.com/topic/393904-cannot-connect-to-0002-streetsmart-edge/?source=email (this one is newer)

Comment: Thanks. Already used `ProxyUseFQDN=Off`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this is a known issue in older versions of Citrix Receiver which comes back in 13.9, so there is nothing Ubuntu related. It only seems to be so because Citrix Receiver 13.9 and Ubuntu 18.04 were released in the same period of time.

I got this insight from [Cannot connect to "0.0.0.2 a Citrix server farm - Published app name" Most Distros](https://discussions.citrix.com/topic/323985-cannot-connect-to-0002-published-app-name-most-distros/#comment-2004606)

So to resolve it install Citrix Receiver 13.8.

Comment: Consider accepting the top answer, please...

Answer (score 18):

Running the below commands after installing the Citrix Receiver Full worked for me

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/* /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts/

sudo c_rehash /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts/
```

Comment: Thanks! the cleanest of all it works like a charm ubuntu 18.04 citrix 13.10 only 2 commands and all issue fixed.

Comment: This resolved the issue for me running Ubuntu 18.04 and Citrix Workspace for Linux Version 18.9.0.6. Would be great if you could add a short description what these commands are doing. If I get it right, it's adding default ca certs used by Mozilla to Citrix's keystore, isn't it?

Comment: Worked for me too :)

Comment: This worked for me too. I am a Citrix Administrator with 15 Years of Experience. I was hoping that Citrix would fix this in the current 19.1 Release. Alas! that is not the case

Comment: Clean solution! This worked for me too. I am running with linux mint 19 and citrix receiver 13.10.

Comment: works in Debian Buster too

Comment: Work for me like a charm. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem after upgrading to 18.04 from 17.04.
Firefox gave the same error message.
I found a work-around: Start Citrix Receiver directly from the Launcher (Supe+A).
Enter a copy from the url you can still find on the Firefox page.

Btw: Still using citrix Receiver 13.5

Comment: You need to provide better answer with more information.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer is given here:

https://discussions.citrix.com/topic/402745-citrix-workspace-app-1903-install-fails-on-ubuntu-1904/

Altough it refers to an issue on Ubuntu 19.04 it also applies to 18.04 this way like I found out, but the difference is that these packages are in the standard distribution available and just need to be installed from there:

It says (and for sure you have to adjust the versions of the packages accordingly)

"You can manually install the dependencies and then Citrix:

1. Download the 3 required dependencies from Launchpad (not providing direct links so you can check it's legit):

a. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/amd64/libicu60/60.2-3ubuntu3 (libicu60_60.2-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb (7.7 MiB))

b. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/amd64/libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0/2.4.11-3ubuntu3

(libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0_2.4.11-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb (1.8 MiB))

c. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/cosmic/amd64/libwebkitgtk-1.0-0/2.4.11-3ubuntu3

(libwebkitgtk-1.0-0_2.4.11-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb (7.7 MiB))

2. Install the files in that order in the terminal

(assuming the files are in the Downloads folder)

cd ~/Downloads
sudo dpkg -i libicu60_60.2-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0_2.4.11-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libwebkitgtk-1.0-0_2.4.11-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i icaclient_19.3.0.5_amd64.deb

This correctly installs Citrix Workspace. If you then get connection errors when trying to set it up, also implement step 3.

3. Fix the certificate error.

sudo ln -s /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/* /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts/
sudo c_rehash /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts/

That's all."