# Unable to remote access using Citrix Receiver

Tags: networking, vpn, citrix

I installed Citrix Receiver in my Linux versions (Ubuntu, Elementary, Mint).
In all machines, the same problem.

I installed many versions: Citrix Receiver 13.0, 13.6, 13.7, 13.10 and the same problem.

Obs( I tried these solutions: [Use Citrix Receiver (ICA client) on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033504/use-citrix-receiver-ica-client-on-ubuntu-18-04))

I wait a long time, and it shows an error message.

In my attempts I used FireFox, Epiphany and Chrome.

I'm using a VPN.

#### My Step By Step

Download Citrix Receiver:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Install Citrix using:
`dpkg -i <filename>.deb`
and
`sudo apt-get -f install`

Access the corporate's site to remote access:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

When I click on the link:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

It tries to connect for a long time:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

And it shows an error message:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]